# Icons and imagery rights

Tags: image, copyright, licensing

Can someone tell me if the icons and images of TravianZ [in this GitHub project](https://github.com/Shadowss/TravianZ) are public domain?

I need to create a similar game and need only the town / buildings images. Seems the project was abandoned so I don't know who to ask.

Comment: Jesus Christ guys ... stop downvoting. Ask to delete so you will not burn all of my points.

Comment: Serious problem with this site.  A downvote with no explanation does *nothing* but discourage users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image folders of that repository contain this notice:

```
#################################################################################
##              -= YOU MAY NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE THIS NOTICE =-                 ##
## --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ##
##  Filename       404.tpl                                                     ##
##  Developed by:  aggenkeech                                                  ##
##  License:       TravianX Project                                            ##
##  Copyright:     TravianX (c) 2010-2012. All rights reserved.                ##
##                                                                             ##
#################################################################################
```

So it looks as though these assets were copied from a previous adaptation of the game, and the prior copyright would still apply to them.

If you cannot find a statement from the authors releasing these assets into the public domain, then they are not in the public domain. Not enough time has passed from the date shown above for the original creators' copyright to pass into public domain.

Comment: Sad. I would love to use these images. Thank you.